# data member 'vec' cannot be a member template

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have the following two lines in a header in order to declare a vector containing a template:

```
template <class t>
std::vector <t> vec;
```

However I get the following error:

```
data member 'vec' cannot be a member template
```

What did I do wrong?

Edit: I don't know that I was understood correctly, I am trying to declare a vector which contains a template, I know that this can be done since one can have the following:

```
template <class T>
void funct(vector <T> v){

}
```

This function takes a vector of a template as its parameter.  I wish to do the same thing except with declaring the vector in a header in order to allow the vector to contain anything.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? `std::vector` needs a template parameter and you are not providing one.

Comment: my bad posted incorrectly

Comment: It works [fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fa534fe247eb921117923287a1046596-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

Answer (score 10):

The `template <>` statement is only used when **declaring** a *function template* or a *class template*. For example you can use it when you declare (and define) a class:

```
template <typename T>
class TemplateClass {
    /* definition */
};
```

Or a function:

```
template <typename T>
void templateFunc(T value) {
    /* definition */
}
```

When creating an *instance* of the class, you can't use the `template <>` statement. Instead you specify a template parameter like this:

```
TemplateClass<int> tc;
```

And when calling a template function:

```
int i = 1;
templateFunc(i); // <-- Automatic template deduction to int.
```

Answer (score 3):

Such a vector can't contain anything.

Let's suppose that a compiler lets you declare such a vector and you write:

```
//...
A Aobj;
vec.push_back(Aobj);
//...
```

Then the size of one element in `vec` will be the `sizeof(A)`. But next you write:

```
//...
B Bobj;
vec.push_back(Bobj);
//...
```

What will the size of one element here be?

Anyway, as a workaround you may declare `vector<void*> vec` so the vector can contain a pointer to anything you want.

Comment: Yes, but the `void *` will make him lose all type information. The best way would be to use `Variant` (from **boost**, or implement your own).

Comment: @MaximeOudot I agree. C++11 or 14 even supports `union` for custom `class`es, no need to use other libs.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer applies to C++11 and earlier*

---

There is no such thing as templated data members. The only sorts of templates are *class template* and *function template*. Your other example is a function template.

Try and think about how someone would instantiate your class. Suppose it was legal to do:

```
struct S
{
    template<typename T> 
    T x;
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.x = ????
}
```

The type of `S` must be known in order to do `S s;`, it can't magically change to accommodate whatever type you decide to give to `x`. In fact you couldn't even evaluate `s.x` .

To solve your problem you have to make the template parameter be a template parameter of the class containing the data member, e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    vector<T> vec;
};

int main()
{
    S<int> s;
    s.vec = vector<int>(5);
}
```

Comment: C++17 added support for template variables

Comment: @Michael actually they were added in C++14

Answer (score -1):

Vector always need a class T as template. But the template  should be put ahead of class declaration.

You probably mean

```
template<class T> 
class A {
private:
std::vector<T> vec;
};
```