# How can I have an object with differing parameter types while it's also in a vector?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, vector

I currently wish to have a vector of objects where each object has differing properties.

**Intended outcome:**

```
//v is a vector
v.push_back(ttSaveObj(5, "int example"));
v.push_back(ttSaveObj("Hello, world!", "string example"));

std::cout << v[0].data << " " << v[0].variableName << std::endl; //Intended Output: 5 int example
std::cout << v[1].data << " " << v[1].variableName << std::endl; //Intended Output: Hello, world! string example
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199744/data-member-vec-cannot-be-a-member-template/23904055#23904055) I tried having a constructor function for the class with `<void*>` in the template, but this seems just create a pointer to `void` (as I partially expected).

**ttSaveObj.hpp:**

```
template <typename T>
class ttSaveObj {
  public:

    ttSaveObj(T pVar, std::string pName) {
      data = pVar;
      variableName = pName;
    };
    ~ttSaveObj() {};

    std::string variableName;
    T data;
};
```

**ttGameObj.hpp:**

```
#include "ttSaveObj.hpp"

class ttGameObj {
  public:

    ttGameObj();
    ~ttGameObj();
    std::vector<ttSaveObj<void*>> data;
};
```

**ttGameObj.cpp:**

```
#include "ttGameObj.hpp"

ttGameObj::ttGameObj() {
  int asdf = 5;
  int * test = &asdf;
  data.push_back(ttSaveObj<void*>(test, "X"));
  std::cout << &data[0].data << " " << data[0].variableName << std::endl; //Output: 0x15fb770 X
}
```

Anything that will help me get closer to my intended outcome is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `std::cout << &data[0].data` should be `std::cout << (*(int*)data[0].data)`, but it will be undefined behaviour after `int asdf = 5;` goes out of scope.

Comment: You could use a `vector<unique_ptr<Base>>` and implement derived classes for `int`, `string`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects you put in the vector seem to have two data members: `variableName`, which is of fixed `std::string` type, and a `data` field, which is of *varying* type.

You may consider using [C++17's `std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (or Boost's `variant` implementation) for the `data` field. For example, if you plan to support the types `int`, `float` and `std::string` for your `data`, you can use a  `std::variant<int, float, std::string>`.

There's also [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), if you want to store instances of *any* type (that satisfy the requirements described in the [`std::any` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)).

In *modern* C++ I'd suggest to avoid the C-style `void*`, and use it only if strictly necessary (e.g. if you are at some legacy C API boundary): there are safer, more robust and higher-level alternatives to it.

---

Another option (if it makes better sense for your design) is to define a base class (**interface**) for the objects you want to put in your vector, and define custom classes that implement this interface. In this case, I suggest using *smart* pointers (like e.g. `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`) to manage those objects in a simple and safe way (I saw another answer here that used raw pointers, requiring explicit `new`/`delete` - actually in that code there were `new`s but no `delete`, with consequent resource leaks).

E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Interface for an element to be inserted in the vector
class IElement
{
public:
    IElement() {}
    virtual ~IElement() {}

    virtual string ToString() = 0;

    // Other virtual methods ...
};

class IntElement : public IElement
{
public:
    explicit IntElement(int n) : _n{ n } {}

    virtual string ToString() override
    {
        return to_string(_n);
    }

private:
    int _n;
};

class StringElement : public IElement
{
public:
    explicit StringElement(const string& s) : _s{ s } {}

    virtual string ToString() override
    {
        return _s;
    }

private:
    string _s;
};

int main() 
{
    vector<shared_ptr<IElement>> elements;
    elements.push_back(make_shared<IntElement>(10));
    elements.push_back(make_shared<IntElement>(20));
    elements.push_back(make_shared<StringElement>("Hello"));
    elements.push_back(make_shared<StringElement>("World"));

    for (const auto& e : elements)
    {
        cout << e->ToString() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 10
> 20
> Hello
> World
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 then you can use the tuple class in the standard library. You could make this object like so:

```
auto v = std::make_tuple(ttSaveObj(5, "int example"), ttSaveObj("Hello, world!", "string example"))
std::cout << std::get<0>(v).data << " " << std::get<0>(v).variableName << std::endl;
```

There is a drawback though that the index for access is a template argument and must therefore be known at compile time, meaning that you can't loop through the elements. Also the types of the elements in the tuple must be known at compile time.

Comment: You can go through the elements of a tuple, you just have to use a library function rather than a language feature. There already exist tuple-foreach functions out there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your goals correctly, Java-like approach could take place, but you should wrap the vector to never forget the clean up.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory>

using std::vector;

class Object 
{
public:

    explicit Object() {}
    virtual ~Object() {}

    virtual const char* toString() const = 0;

};

class StringObject : public Object
{
public:
    explicit StringObject(const char* string) : Object()
    {
        if(string != 0)
        {
            m_value = new char[strlen(string) + 1];
            strcpy(((char*)m_value), string);
        } else
        {
            m_value = new char[1];
            m_value[0] = 0;
        }
    }
    virtual ~StringObject()
    {
        delete m_value;
    }


    virtual const char* toString() const
    {
        return (const char*)m_value;   
    }
private:
    char* m_value;
};

class IntObject : public Object
{
public:
    explicit IntObject(int val) : Object()
    {
        m_value = val;
    }
    virtual ~IntObject()
    {
    }


    virtual const char* toString() const
    {
        return std::to_string(m_value).c_str();
    }
private:
    int m_value;
};

int main()
{

    auto vec = vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>();
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<IntObject>(9));
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<IntObject>(11));
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<StringObject>("hello"));
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<StringObject>("world"));

    for(const auto& v : vec)
    {
        std::cout << v.get()->toString() << " ";
    }

}
```

Output, as expected, "9 11 hello world".

Comment: *never* use `delete`, use smart pointers instead (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`), e.g. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>`.